# Yii CArrayDataProvider sorting all columns

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, gridview-sorting

Hi I would like to set a sorting to all fields in a CGridView without having to write them down manually. Any ideas?

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.GridView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($offers,array(
                    'sort'=>array(
                        'attributes'=> 'AUTOMATICALLY TAKE ALL',
                    ),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageSize'=>10,
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                'enableSorting'=>true,
                ...
```

Now I have to write all columns(=attributes) I want to sort on. But I just want all that are defined in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need asterisk feature, 'cause you can use keys from array:

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.GridView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($offers,array(
                        'sort'=>array(
                            'attributes'=> array_keys($offers[0]),
                        ),  
                        ...
```

Comment: this seems to be a nice workaround, but what happens, if there are no entries? Of course if no entries, than no sort is needed, so as long as it does not throw an error it seems fine

Comment: Yeah, it's fast hack. I prefer to prepare sort attributes in model and get names from columns array. Columns array is prepared in model too.

Answer (score 0):

It should work only for CActiveDataProvider, see [CSort.php source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/CSort.php), method resolveAttribute.

```
public function resolveAttribute($attribute)
{
    if($this->attributes!==array())
        $attributes=$this->attributes;
    elseif($this->modelClass!==null)
        $attributes=$this->getModel($this->modelClass)->attributeNames();
    else
        return false;
    foreach($attributes as $name=>$definition)
    {
        if(is_string($name))
        {
            if($name===$attribute)
                return $definition;
        }
        elseif($definition==='*')
        {
            if($this->modelClass!==null && $this->getModel($this->modelClass)->hasAttribute($attribute))
                return $attribute;
        }
        elseif($definition===$attribute)
            return $attribute;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hm, but that does not help me, as I want to use `CArrayDataProvider`.. so there is no option fir this in this?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible